# Ubuntu.css owner issue

Tags: 18.04, gnome, permissions, themes

I edited `ubuntu.css` in `usr>share>gnome-shell>theme` to add a unlock screen background image. Looks like my attempt to edit it as administrator messed up `owner` permissions. For other files in the theme folder the owner is root. For the existing `ubuntu.css` , it is as below

[image]

The problem is since the owner is not root ( I assume ), the background image is not loaded during the first boot. Once I boot and then lock the screen, the background image is available for the unlock screen.

Kindly tell me how to change permissions in such a way that background image appears during first boot as well. Thanks.

Comment: whats the output of `sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3.css`

Comment: Thanks @PRATAP I managed to find a solution here : http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/chown.1.html

Answer (score 1):

I used

```
sudo chown root:root ubuntu.css
```

It works for now. The above commands change the owner and group permissions to root.